# What is the best practice to get the updates from another repo without making any PR after changes?

Tags: github, github-pages, git-clone, git-fork

I'd like to know how to proceed in GitHub where I could to be able to get the updates from the original repo but prevent opening a PR after each time I push a change made by myself?

The concept I want to apply this is to use a blog template for my GitHub pages. I'd like to get the feature for the future if the contributors would make any but at the same time, I'd like to prevent pushing anything to the original repo as a PR since those commits wouldn't include anything related to making a contribution to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRs aren't generated automatically, you need to explicitly create them from a branch.

You can fork a repo and work on it, and when needed, fetch and rebase from the original repo you forked from. As long as you don't explicitly use this repo to create PRs on the original repo, you should be fine.

**EDIT** - Adding some details as per the last comment:

Assume there's a repo called `something` owned by `someone`. You can start off by forking it to `youruser` using the GitHub UI. Then you can clone your fork and work on it:

```
git clone https://github.com/youruser/something.git
```

In order to get the recent changes from the original `someone/something` repo, you need to set it up as a remote. By convention you'd call this remote your "upstream", but you can really give it any name you choose:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/someone/something.git
```

Once you've added it as a remote, you can fetch from it and rebase on top of it:

```
git fetch upstream && git rebase upstream/main
```

(note that using the `main` branch is just an example. You can of course rebase on top of any branch in the remote repo)

Comment: could you be a bit more explicit by giving an example in the command line?

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik for the explanatory steps. I get the idea better right now. With the last step you say that even though I push changes to my main, they won't as a PR on the original project repo, right? Though, I'll be able to pull the new features from the original one.

Comment: @Nihat - yes, the two are unrelated. A PR won't be created unless you explicitly create one. Creating or not creating a PR won't effect your ability to pull changes from the `upstream` repo

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible because when you clone or fork that repo, from that time, you start to add your own content to it since it's your personal blog. So you cannot keep getting the features from main repo. Maybe you can try `rebase` but I'm not sure if it works for this case. Or you can add those features to your repo by your own whenever you need them.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of :) So, _cloning_ seems to be the only option if I don't want to affect any place with my commits but this time I would lack the updates.